# What is the convention for type annotating trivial lines of code that instantiate a class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

As I'm unable to find a better way to phrase the question, I'm not able to find any reasonable discussions on the topic.

Consider the following:

```
import queue
my_queue: queue.Queue = queue.Queue()
```

I have been annotating code as shown above for a long time. However, each time I do so, I feel strange. Consider the alternative:

```
import queue
my_queue = queue.Queue()
```

The latter seems to be superior in terms of readability (at least for me). However, afraid that some tool or the other may be unable to discern the appropriate type for `my_queue`, I have always written the former.

This can especially be a problem when the type in question is very long (and the code starts to look more akin to Java rather than Python). I am aware of the fact that aliasing a type is possible. Regardless, I feel that the latter is more readable for humans.

Has this topic perhaps been addressed in a PEP? Do any tools (for documentation, linting, analysis, etc.) behave differently in either case?

Comment: If there exists a type checker out there (which I doubt) that is unable to infer the type `my_queue` in this example without the explicit type annotation it should never be used by anybody.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

The convention is to **not annotate** a variable, to which you are assigning the output of a class instantiation, unless that class is a strict subtype of the type you want the variable to hold.

---

### Sensible type checkers

Generally speaking you should operate under the assumption that any type checker worth its salt will automatically infer the type of a variable once you assign it for the first time.<sup>1</sup>

There are essentially two possible situations:

1. You assign a literal.
2. You assign the output of a function.

In the first case the type is obvious because you are using a literal.<sup>2</sup>

```py
a = 1
b = 3.14
c = "foo"
d = [1, 2]
```

Any usable type checker will *infer*:

```py
a: int
b: float
c: str
d: list[int]
```

In the second case it depends on the function used and what its return type annotation is.

If a function has a return type annotation, that will obviously be the type inferred for the variable to which you assign the output of that function:

```py
def spam() -> str:
    return "eggs"

s = spam()  # inferred as `str`
```

Your initial example of instantiating a **class** is essentially a special case of this because you are *calling* the class to get an instance of it.

```py
class Thing:
    ...

t = Thing()  # inferred as `Thing`
```

Every type checker *must* assume that the return type of a class is... well, that class! Therefore adding an annotation to that assignment is redundant.<sup>3</sup>

Where it really makes sense to add type hints is when the function being called is *not* typed. Strict type checkers will complain about even calling such functions in the first place, but to make sense of what that variable should hold, you *have* to annotate it:

```py
def func():
    ...

var = func()  # inferred as `Any`
```

But this is *never* the case with classes because **they themselves are the type**.

---

**Footnotes**:

<sup>1</sup> There are edge-cases, mostly with generic types, where the assignment is ambiguous because some type arguments were not set and could not be inferred.

<sup>2</sup> An example, where this may still cause issues with some stricter type checkers is again with generic types like `list`. Initializing an *empty* list for example and then appending to it will cause Mypy to complain because it wants you to be explicit about whether or not the type should *really* be `list[Any]` or something more useful. Example:

```py
l = []

for item in range(4):
    l.append(l)  # error: Need type annotation for "l" (hint: "l: List[<type>] = ...")  [var-annotated]
```

<sup>3</sup> An exception to this rule might be when you are dealing with subtypes and you want the variable to be typed as the *supertype*, but initially assign a subtype:

```py
x = 0
...
x = 3.14  # error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float", variable has type "int")  [assignment]
```

Here the type checker infers `x` as `int` and then complains because we assign a `float` to it, which is *not a subtype*  of `int`. It is the other way around, `int` is a subtype of `float`. So we could make it clear that `x` is supposed to hold `float` values even though we assign an `int` at first:

```py
x: float = 0
...
x = 3.14
```

This is perfectly fine.

To transfer this to your example, if you had a class `SubQueue` inheriting from `Queue` and you wanted `my_queue` to be created with an instance of `SubQueue`, but also later re-assign `my_queue` some other `Queue` instance, then you should do `my_queue: Queue = SubQueue()`.

---

Here is a [Mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=44e4935c0175402afdc1ebd87a82e19e) with the examples from above.

Answer (score 0):

Type annotations have been addressed in [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/), introducing type hints and their usage. However, the PEP does not enforce specific styles or rules.

Some excerpts I found to be useful:

> It should also be emphasized that Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.

> While annotations are normally the best format for type hints, there are times when it is more appropriate to represent them by a special comment, or in a separately distributed stub file. (See below for examples.)

> Annotations should be kept simple or static analysis tools may not be able to interpret the values. For example, dynamically computed types are unlikely to be understood.

However, I have not found a specific paragraph regarding instantiation of user-created classes. My approach to go with the balance of adding type hints whenever it seems necessary and beneficial, but leaving them out if they serve little to no purpose.

For your example, since it is quite obvious that calling `queue.Queue()` will return an object of type `queue.Queue`, I would definitely leave the type hints out.